# Integrate Two Dot-Product-Power Terms

Tags: integration

I need to compute something like the following integral:$$
\int_{\Omega_\vec{a}} \left< \vec{x} \cdot \vec{b} \right>^n \left(\vec{x}\cdot\vec{a}\right)^m d\vec{x}
$$Notational issues:

- The integral is over the unit hemisphere centered at $\vec{a}$.
- All vectors ($\vec{x}$, $\vec{a}$, and $\vec{b}$) lie on this hemisphere.
- $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ are known constants.
- I have abused the $\left<\cdot\right>$ notation to mean "clamp-to-nonnegative-numbers".  Note: this could have been applied on the second term too, but it isn't necessary since $\vec{x}\cdot\vec{a}$ is never less than $0$.

The main issue I had while integrating is the first term.  You can get rid of the clamp-to-zero problem by doing a basis transformation so that you're integrating around the hemisphere centered at $\vec{b}$, but then this *creates* the opposite problem on the second term!

I also tried converting the first term to a trigonometric form, but this is somewhat difficult.  I could probably do it, but it's not clear that the problem could be solved that way.

Question: Is this family of integrals solvable?  Does removing the clamp-to-zero constraint make it easier?